# How see duplications from last analysis?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to analyze the programmers profile. So I'm looking for people that is duplicating code, and trying to understand why they're doing this.
My idea is identify (if is lazy, lack of knowledge, etc) and attack the problem in root.
Is there anyway to see only the duplications added ONLY in last analysis of SonarQube?

Comment: Just checked on nemo and the time machine view just tells you how much code duplication was added since last analysis, but doesn't actually link to the new issues unlike other metrics. Guess it's not supported yet?

Comment: Yes, I didn't found anything too. Thanks for fast answer. Can you post this comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked on nemo and the time machine view just tells you how much code duplication was added since last analysis, but doesn't actually link to the new issues unlike other metrics. Most likely it's not supported yet..